# Loading a UIPicker to a predetermined spot

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

If I have a basic array such as:

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Object1",@"Object2",@"Object3",nil];
self.pickerData = array;
[array release];
```

The picker will be on "Object1" when the view is loaded.  How can I have the picker start off settled on "Object2"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `[picker selectRow:1 inComponent:0 animated:YES];`

Comment: if this was the right solution for you, please mark this as correct answer.